# Locking a KV with consul

Tags: consul, consul-kv

I am trying to acquire a lock on a KV pair on consul while updating it, so no one else can update it.

Initially I have

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/hosts?raw
{"k1":"v1"}
```

Now I get a session

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:8500/v1/session/create
{"ID":"9ed55585-ddda-4605-a926-d1e0b57a9919"}
```

I then acquire a lock on KV

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/hosts?acquire=9ed55585-ddda-4605-a926-d1e0b57a9919
```

Now when I release and do a GET, my values are empty

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/hosts?release=9ed55585-ddda-4605-a926-d1e0b57a9919

curl -XGET http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/hosts?raw => This returns empty
```

Am I doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get nothing back because you **did not send any data to write** in your `PUT` request to the kv store.

Here is the same commands, with some pretty printing.

**Create a session**

```
 curl --request PUT http://localhost:8500/v1/session/create
 {"ID":"3619d9fd-8b8f-0b89-acdf-8d752b38a754"}
```

**Write a value**

Using a Linux "here file", I will write the value "Hello, World" under the `host` key. Remeber to use the session ID you got back from the previous command. Copy/Paste the 3 lines as a single unit.

```
curl --request PUT http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/host?acquire=3619d9fd-8b8f-0b89-acdf-8d752b38a754 --data @- << EOF
Hello, World
EOF
```

**Read the value back**

Reading is just a GET, that I piped to a pretty printer.

```
curl -s http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/host| python -m json.tool
[
    {
        "CreateIndex": 3832257,
        "Flags": 0,
        "Key": "host",
        "LockIndex": 1,
        "ModifyIndex": 3832260,
        "Session": "3619d9fd-8b8f-0b89-acdf-8d752b38a754",
        "Value": "SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxk"
    }
]
```

That base64 blob is the data we wrote the first time

```
echo "SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxk" | openssl base64 -d -A
Hello, World
```

**Try to write the value whithout the lock**

This does not work like you think. The [K/V documentation](https://www.consul.io/api/kv.html#create-update-key) says this

> an update that does not include the acquire parameter will proceed
>   normally even if another session has locked the key

**Delete the session**

You could set a TTL to your session and wait for it to expire, but let's delete it.

```
curl --request PUT http://localhost:8500/v1/session/destroy/3619d9fd-8b8f-0b89-acdf-8d752b38a754
```

The value is still there, but not associated with a session anymore:

```
curl -s http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/host| python -m json.tool
[
    {
        "CreateIndex": 3832257,
        "Flags": 0,
        "Key": "host",
        "LockIndex": 0,
        "ModifyIndex": 3832331,
        "Value": "SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxk"
    }
]
```

If you want keys to be deleted when the session expires or is deleted, specify `"Behavior": "delete"` when you create the session

```
curl --request PUT http://localhost:8500/v1/session/create --data @- << EOF
{
    "Name": "Helps with debugging",
    "Behavior": "delete",
    "TTL": "2m"
}
EOF
{"ID":"45c17b06-b632-d17f-b0af-b2bee8f82511"}
```